# Unable to run mariadb in a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, innodb, docker-container

I'm not very familiar with using Docker yet. I am using Docker on a Debian server. I tried running MariaDB over a Docker container, that worked so far. However, lately I always get an error.
This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  repository:
    container_name: repository
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    restart: always
    networks:
      main:
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=root_password --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 15
    networks:
      main:
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE: "yes"
      MARIADB_USER: user
      MARIADB_DATABASE: database
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - "mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql"
networks:
  main:
volumes:
  mariadb-data:
```

When I look at the logs of the container, the following appears:

```
2022-04-24 13:47:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.7.3+maria~focal started.
2022-04-24 13:47:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-04-24 13:47:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.7.3+maria~focal started.
2022-04-24 13:47:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade information missing, assuming required
2022-04-24 13:47:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2022-04-24 13:47:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [Note] mariadbd (server 10.7.3-MariaDB-1:10.7.3+maria~focal) starting as process 49 ...
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=3821844,3821844
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CHECKPOINT at 3821844 between the checkpoint 3821844 and the end 3821868.
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2022-04-24 13:47:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-04-24 13:47:55 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-04-24 13:47:55 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-04-24 13:47:55 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-04-24 13:47:55 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-04-24 13:47:55 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

What is the reason for this error and how can i fix this?

Comment: Maybe this could help https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/322

Comment: What version where you upgrading from? Can you try your previous version running with [innodb-fast-shutdown=1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_fast_shutdown), and then try the new 10.7.3 version. Failing that try `quay.io/mariadb-foundation/mariadb-devel:10.7` as the latest development version soon to be released (sometime in next two weeks). [bug reports](https://jira.mariadb.org) welcome.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue caused by a previous mysql install.

It can be solved by deleting or renaming the folder where the volume is referred to (mariadb-data) and then deleting+restarting the current container/all containers just to be sure:

```
docker stop $ (docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $ (docker ps -a -q)
```

*In this command, docker ps -a -q is used to display a list of IDs of all Docker containers, and docker rm is used to delete them.*

Now the container should start normally.